# Facebook profile pic used as avatar

Tags: facebook, avatar

I'm trying to add an avatar option for my blog and would like to avoid using Gravatar or custom avatars so I wish to use Facebook profile pic instead of an avatar.
I know that there are plugins for that but they're all a bit cumbersome.

I tried [Incarnate](http://www.visitmix.com/labs/incarnate/) but the issue with it is that there is no authentication so anyone can use any publicly available username thus misrepresenting themselves. Also, if a person doesn't have a publicly available FB profile, they can't use their profile pic.

To sum up, I'd like a plugin or a code so that visitors to my blog are automatically represented with their FB profile pic (if they are already logged in to Facebook) without the need for them to register or log in with FB details to my blog.
If a person is not logged in to FB, then a custom avatar is to be used.
Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To sum up, I'd like a plugin or a code so that visitors to my blog are
>   automatically represented with their FB profile pic (if they are
>   already logged in to Facebook) without the need for them to register
>   or log in with FB details to my blog.

There is no possible way to do this. You cannot get somebody's Facebook information without them first "connecting" to your site via a Facebook Application.

In short, if you are limiting your question to this condition (the visitor not connecting to your site in some manner and thus granting permissions via an FB application), then it cannot be done in any way whatsoever.

Comment: No, I meant that they don't have to log in to FB account specifically (i.e. no additional steps) while on my site just as you don't have to log in to click Like button on a post if you're already logged in to facebook.com.

Comment: Yes, I understand what your question is. The answer is correct. You cannot retrieve information about who they are on Facebook without them connecting to your application in some manner. It is not possible. A Like button isn't the same thing, because the like button is an iframe, it's not giving you any information, it's talking directly between the user's browser and Facebook's own servers.

Comment: Is it then possible to have an iframe like you have when you use facebook comments on your blog but that it only displays facebook avatar and the rest of the comments design is custom (i.e. HTML(PHP)+CSS)?

Comment: No, because you need to store the information about the user in order to display their avatar later. Displaying their avatar only to them would be kind of pointless. In other words, using a frame or similar such that they see their avatar but you don't get the information to display their avatar to others doesn't really solve the problem you're trying to solve. You need to get some of their FB info, and you can't do that without them authorizing you to do so in some manner.

Comment: OK, I get that so I'll reformulate my question: can I have my comment design but so that the users use their FB account while commenting? (But I want the comments to be visible only on my page and not have them posted on their FB profiles like I see with some other webpages.) Sorry for being so weird but I'm just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: It is possible, but not without getting them to click a button and approve your application to get their information. My own Simple Facebook Connect plugin will do this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/

Comment: OK, it seems promising.
Could you please post a site with working version to see how it in action.

Comment: It's running on my own site, http://ottopress.com. I'm also running Simple Twitter Connect and Simple Google Connect on there (also mine)

Comment: OK, looks great. To use all three connect version like you have at your site, do I just install all three plugins?
Also, can I change CSS for the comments (odd, even, author, comment fields)?

Comment: P.S. Your unicornify plugin is very interesting... It's a great way to have the same avatar for users without the need to register.